# QComboBox in the QTableWitget does not work properly

Tags: qt

I implement custom delegate for QTableWidget to edit cell data like QComboBox.
All works fine except one.

When user selects something in the combobox this changes does not applied while user will select another cell. 
The method QStyledItemDelegate::setModelData() of custom delegate not calling. So, user's changes are not applied.

What I should to do, to apply value in the combobox, after user makes selection?

Answer (score 4):

Your delegate should send the `commitData` signal when you want to write data to model. It will cause calling `setModelData`. In your case you need to emit `commitData` when `QComboBox::currentIndexChanged` signal is emitted by the widget.

Comment: Thanks! can I solve this task without signals, because I do not use moc?

Comment: thats definitely a right answer, I am just wondering what are the reasons you can't use moc while using Qt? No offence at all, I am really very interested if there are any circumstances where such approach is applicable

Comment: Qt 5 allows to use signals and slots without moc. See [New Signal Slot Syntax in Qt 5](http://qt-project.org/wiki/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax).

Comment: New Syntax describes how to connect signals and slots, but not how to emit.

Comment: Signals are just normal functions. Just call it. `emit` keyword is an empty define and can be omitted.